# Friend object doesn't disappear after deleting from the set in a relationship ManyToMany

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm working on a system where users can "friend". I wanted to add an opportunity to delete a friend, but for some reason friend stays in database. I'm new in Spring Boot and Hibernate, so i dont't get what i'm doing wrong.

So, this is my User class where I have Set of friends

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
})
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;

    private String name, username, email, password;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "user_friend",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend_id")
    )
    public Set<User> friends=new HashSet<>();

    public void addFriend(User friend){
        this.friends.add(friend);
        friend.getFriends().add(this);
    }
    public void removeFriend(User friend){
        this.friends.remove(friend);
        friend.getFriends().remove(this);
    }
    ***
}
```

And there is how i'm trying to delete a friend in Service class

```
public void deleteFriend(Long userId, Long friendId) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(
                        () -> new RuntimeException(String.format("User with id %d not found", userId))
                );

        User friend = userRepository.findById(friendId)
                .orElseThrow(
                        () -> new RuntimeException(String.format("User with id %d not found", friendId))
                );


        System.out.println(user.friends);
        System.out.println("Starting deleting");
        user.removeFriend(friend);
        System.out.println(user.friends);
        System.out.println("Finishing deleting");
```

And that's what i have in a console:

```
[com.carrot.VMeste.models.users.User@74c262c7, com.carrot.VMeste.models.users.User@41d8a002]
Starting deleting
Hibernate: 
    select
        f1_0.user_id,
        f1_1.user_id,
        f1_1.created_at,
        f1_1.email,
        f1_1.expires_at,
        f1_1.is_delete,
        f1_1.last_login,
        f1_1.name,
        f1_1.password,
        f1_1.registered,
        f1_1.updated_at,
        f1_1.username 
    from
        user_friend f1_0 
    join
        users f1_1 
            on f1_1.user_id=f1_0.friend_id 
    where
        f1_0.user_id=?
[com.carrot.VMeste.models.users.User@41d8a002]
Finishing deleting
```

It seems, that friend is deleted from Set and everything is okey, but actually friend stayed in database, and if I try to delete a friend again, console shows me the same log, where in the start user have 2 friends on his friend set.

I dont get, why this is happening. And I'm not really getting, what exactly happening in Hibernate log, shouldn't it use the command delete for what i'm trying to do? i'm just generally confused.

And maybe there's is a better way for a friend system than many-to-many relationship on the same table.How normal is this approach in principle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't shown us where a transaction was started. Do you have a ```@Transactional``` annotation on your ```deleteFriend()``` method?

Comment: You didn't specify `CascadeType.REMOVE` on the `@ManyToMany` relationship.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting ManyToMany relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006764/deleting-manytomany-relationship)

Comment: @LeeGreiner, i added Transactional annotation and it worked! Thank you! I'll go read more about this...

Comment: Based on your output, it also looks like you are obtaining each user's friends lazily. You could fetch them eagerly when looking up each user by adding a repository method to do so. ```@Query("select user from User user join fetch user.friends friend where user.userId= :userId)``` This would potentially save you 2 trips to the database.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are missing to save the action. you have two options.

a) add the transactional annotation to the method that it is doing the delete action.

b) save the action on your entity with your repository.

```
        user.removeFriend(friend);

        userRepository.save(user);

        System.out.println(user.friends);
```